# Efficient persistable recursive data structure

Tags: database, data-structures, recursion, recursive-datastructures

The usual approach with recursive data structures is to have a parent pointer in each object. My problem is that the usual implementation can't answer the questions below in a single operation; instead I need to query my database several times. Is there a solution which gives me the result in a single query?

- Get a list of all children of a node
- Find all parent nodes (== shortest path to the root node)

Note: I'm in the planning stage, so I'm not yet limited to a certain database.

Comment: Does "all children" include children of children?

Comment: @bdonlan: Yes, all including each leaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least Oracle can do [hierarchical queries](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm). Consider example of db users' roles:

```
CREATE TABLE my_dba_role_privs(
   grantee        VARCHAR2(30),
   granted_role   VARCHAR2(30)
);   

-- assigning roles to roles
INSERT INTO my_dba_role_privs( grantee, granted_role ) VALUES('CLIENT', 'SELECT_ORDERS');
INSERT INTO my_dba_role_privs( grantee, granted_role ) VALUES('COMMERCIAL_DEP', 'CREATE_ORDERS');
INSERT INTO my_dba_role_privs( grantee, granted_role ) VALUES('COMMERCIAL_DEP', 'CLIENT');

-- assigning roles to users
INSERT INTO my_dba_role_privs( grantee, granted_role ) VALUES('CL_MATT', 'CLIENT');
INSERT INTO my_dba_role_privs( grantee, granted_role ) VALUES('CL_JOHN', 'CLIENT');
INSERT INTO my_dba_role_privs( grantee, granted_role ) VALUES('CM_MARY', 'COMMERCIAL_DEP');
```

Now select all roles of user 'CM_MARY':

```
SELECT DISTINCT GRANTED_ROLE role_name
  FROM my_dba_role_privs
 START WITH GRANTEE = 'CM_MARY'
       CONNECT BY GRANTEE = PRIOR GRANTED_ROLE;
```

Result:
COMMERCIAL_DEP
CREATE_ORDERS
CLIENT
SELECT_ORDERS

Select all roles and users, who owns role 'CLIENT'

```
SELECT GRANTEE role_name
  FROM my_dba_role_privs
 START WITH GRANTED_ROLE = 'CLIENT'
       CONNECT BY GRANTED_ROLE = PRIOR GRANTEE;
```

Result:
CL_JOHN
CL_MATT
COMMERCIAL_DEP
CM_MARY

**UPDATE:**
Since you mentioned, tree will be pretty static, it may be interesting to try [Joe Celko's Trees](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html) (aprox 180 lines to read).
It doesn't require self joins at all! So, I expect it to perform times faster then CONNECT BY. Though I've just read about it just 30 min ago, and don't know how good it is in real world

**Update2:** "Nested Set Models" with MySQL: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) This is the same as Joe Celko's Trees above but with more examples and explanation.

Comment: Does Oracle cache/index this data efficiently? Or is that more like moving the recursive queries from the app code into the DB layer?

Comment: @Aaron: I haven't found clear answer to this yet, in official docs or on AskTom. From the [off site](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm#i2070828) it seems like Oracle does all that recursive queries, but I'm pretty sure DB is able to do some tricks to improve performance. Regarding my own experience, AFAIK in my company it's used only in one place - to determine all user's roles (as in my post). On our test db we have 3000 rows in `dba_role_privs`, and query executes in 70 ms, which isn't blazing fast, but fine for us

Comment: @Aaron: Also, I've update my answer with pretty interesting link

Comment: The Celko Trees look very promising. At first, I was hesitant because of the cost to manage left and right, but since I change the data structure rarely, that should be OK.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, have you tried Celko trees ? Could you share how they've showed themselves in production (performance, impl, support issues), please ?

Answer (score 2):

If "all children" means only direct children, simply put a list of children, as well as a pointer to the parent on each node. Note that this will make moving a node to another parent more expensive, as all (grand)-children must be updated as well.

If "all children" really means *all* children, one option would be to build a string of the IDs of each parent, and add it as an indexed column. For example, if you have `A`, with the child `B`, with the grandchild `C`, you'd have in `C` a column with value `A/B/C`. Now to find all children of `A` you can simply do a `LIKE` query on `"A/%"`. Again, though, this is expensive when you need to change the parent of a node with children.

If you need to be able to change parents quickly, you're going to need to maintain parent information as a linked list, I think. You could, however, use a stored procedure to perform this query operation with only one database round trip.

Comment: +1 My tree structure is pretty static (places in the real world), so I need no move op. I will often need to query B/* but I can make this efficient by looking up the parent path from an item (so I don't need `like '%/B/%'` but can use the more efficient `like '/A/B/%'`)

Comment: This suggestion more or less matches how the SQL Server 2008 HierarchyId datatype works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx